# How to use NgSweetAlert2 with Angular 4

Tags: css, angular

I want to use ngsweetalert2 (https://github.com/toverux/ngsweetalert2) in angular 4 but the problem is I can't find the css link required.
According to the instructions in the manual I need to import the SweetAlert's CSS file, I tried several links I found on google but none works.

Comment: What module bundler are you using with Angular ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Angular-CLI (I believe you are since it's the standard), you can add styles in the file `.angular-cli.json` at your base project.

**angular-cli.json :**

```
  ...
  "styles": [
    "../node_modules/roboto-fontface/css/roboto/sass/roboto-fontface.scss",
    "../node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
    "../node_modules/ionicons/scss/ionicons.scss",
    "app/theme/theme.scss",
    "styles.scss"
  ],
  ...
```

In here you can add the `.css` and `.scss` files from your libraries, which will add them to the `vendor.bundle.js` served by Angular-CLI.

---

I believe you know that you need to install the library using `NPM` or any other dependency manager to download the library in your `node_modules` folder. In there, you should have the library with the styles at disposal.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Yes, I have installed it through npm but didn't know the css can be imported from there. (I'm new to angular).

Comment: You're welcome !